# I've printed temperature values in one column in a file but want to graph temperature by row

Tags: python, graphing

I want the x-axis to be what row the temperature value is in and the y-axis to be the actual value. How do I do this? I printed values to a file into one column.

Comment: Do you want a histogram? http://matplotlib.org/1.2.1/examples/pylab_examples/histogram_demo.html

Comment: No I'm making a line plot. I have to export the temperatures to a file that look like
900.227416583
803.500551551
712.488023688
629.361934539
555.650926429
492.179610726
439.093140606
and want to graph each value by which row it's in in a line graph

Comment: See http://matplotlib.org/users/pyplot_tutorial.html

Comment: Building off @Hugh, `plt.plot( row, temp)`

Comment: @TylerDavis what does the row contain (x-axis)? Since the y-axis is the x-axis the number of the row?

Comment: each row has a value. it looks like one column of numbers. I want to plot the top number by 0, the second number down as 1 etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# get data
with open("data.txt") as myfile:
    temps = [float(row) for row in myfile]

# generate line numbers
num_rows = len(temps)
rownums = list(range(num_rows))   # starting at 0!

# plot
plt.plot(rownums, temps)
plt.show()
```

which gives

[image]

Comment: what did the file look like that you imported from?

Comment: @Tyler: a text file containing one floating-point number per line

Comment: Thank you so much I calculated the temperature of arbitrary points along a rod heated at one or both ends over time as the temperature spreads and couldn't get it to graph so you are a life saver.